# Create PDF on a Sencha Touch 2.x app wrapped in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, pdf, mobile, sencha-touch-2, cordova

We are developing a mobile app in Sencha Touch 2.x and we need to generate a PDF file on the mobile device. We had a look at a couple of libraries but none of them work once you wrap the app in Phonegap. Does anybody know any libraries to create PDF's using Sencha + Phonegap? because I cannot find any out there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we couldn't find anything so we went with generating the PDF on the server side